# When is the solution to a n initial value problem matrix differential equation invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose $A (t,s)$ a $n\times n$ matrix is the solution of the initial value problem below, where $B_s$ is also an $n\times n$ matrix, invertible for all $s$:

$$\dfrac{d A(t,s)}{ds} = B_s A(t,s)$$
$$ A(t,t) =I_n$$

I know that if $B$ is constant, the solution is invertible as an exponential matrix. If $B_s$ is not constant, is the solution still invertible? My answer is yes since by the Magnus expansion the solution is of the form $A(t,s) = exp(\Omega(t,s))A(t,t)$ which is again is invertible because it's an exponential and $A(t,t)=I_n$. Can anyone confirm if my argument is correct? or is there any other way to see it without using the Magnus expansion argument?

Thanks

Comment: The easiest argument is to use uniqueness of solutions to see that the columns of $A$ must stay linearly independent.

Comment: Or use Liouville's formula: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_formula

Comment: It makes sense. I was not familiar with Liouville's formula but now I know, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I hope you won't mind if I change slightly your notations. We have to deal with the differential system
$$
\dot U=BU,\quad U(0)=I,\tag E
$$
where $B$ is a given matrix depending smoothly on $t$. As you point out, when $B$ is a constant matrix, $U=\exp tB$ and thus is $U$ is invertible. However, it is always the case from the classical relation,
$$
\frac{d}{dt}(\det U)=(\text{trace }{B}) \times(\det U),\tag 1
$$
which implies
$$
(\det U)(t)=(\det U)(0)e^{\int_0^t \text{trace }{B(s) }ds}.\tag 2
$$
Relationship $(2)$ is a nice example of an interesting phenomenon : although there is no simple formula to find $U$  solving $(E)$ (except in some very particular cases such as the constant case),
the determinant of $U$ is easy to determine by $(2)$.